# How to read hardware-level event information from touchscreen?

Tags: linux, touch, hardware, rhel6

I'm working on a project to investigate the possibility of adding touch support to an application and so far the findings have been somewhat disappointing. My company uses Scientific Linux 6.4 (Linux kernel 2.6.32) and so far, I've found information suggesting that 2.6.30+ supports multi-touch HID, but I've also seen information suggesting that the multi-touch in this kernel doesn't work with Xorg interfaces.

Putting aside market availability of touchscreens that are compatible with Linux, is there a way we can verify whether or not multi-touch inputs are generated on the system? We have an older ViewSonic touchscreen that has multi-touch capability, and after looking at the output from the `evtest` tool, I didn't notice any multi-touch events, but I don't know whether `evtest` is reading the touch events from X or the hardware level.

I have no experience dealing with hardware programming or device drivers, so if anyone could give me some guidance on how to verify multi-touch HID compatibility with our version of Linux, whether we have to write our own driver, or read raw data from somewhere, any information you could provide would be great.

**EDIT:** The `evtest` program lists supported events for the device and I don't see anything related to multi-touch, so it doesn't seem like it's supported, but is this an issue with the kernel, the specific device, or something else? The specific monitor I'm testing is a ViewSonic, which is listed as a "Quanta Optical Touchscreen" device. I saw somewhere that a driver for Quanta was added in 2.6.34. Am I just out of luck (for this particular device at least)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and tested the monitor with a laptop that had Linux kernel 4.4.0, and it worked right away, so it seems that it's definitely the kernel. I don't know if there are any touchscreens that WILL work with kernel 2.6.32, but the ones based on the Quanta display definitely don't work.